# Change button text color in listener

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I'm writting simple application and I have problem with changing text color in OnClickListener. I made my own Listener class:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View button) {
    switch (mNumber) {
    case 1:
        mButton1.setTextColor(R.color.white);
        mButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_rounded_rectangle);
        mButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_rounded_rectangle);
        mButton2.setTextColor(R.color.gray);
        mButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_rounded_rectangle);
        mButton3.setTextColor(R.color.gray);
        mImage.setImageResource(mLessonData.getFirstImage(mLesson));
        mComment.setText(mLessonData.setFirstImageComment(mLesson));
        break;
    case 2:
        mButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_rounded_rectangle);
        mButton1.setTextColor(R.color.gray);
        mButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_rounded_rectangle);
        mButton2.setTextColor(R.color.white);
        mButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_rounded_rectangle);
        mButton3.setTextColor(R.color.gray);
        mImage.setImageResource(mLessonData.getSecondImage(mLesson));
        mComment.setText(mLessonData.setSecondImageComment(mLesson));
        break;
    case 3:
        mButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_rounded_rectangle);
        mButton1.setTextColor(R.color.gray);
        mButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_rounded_rectangle);
        mButton2.setTextColor(R.color.gray);
        mButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_rounded_rectangle);
        mButton3.setTextColor(R.color.white);
        mImage.setImageResource(mLessonData.getThirdImage(mLesson));
        mComment.setText(mLessonData.setThirdImageComment(mLesson));
        break;
    }

}
```

background color, change text in TextView and image in ImageView works fine. Problem is with font color in buttons. It always change to dark_grey. Anybody have idea why it works in that way?

definition of colors:

```
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="gray">#AAAAAA</color>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code for color select.

Change:

```
mButton3.setTextColor(R.color.white);
```

to:

```
button.setTextColor(getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.white)); //TAKE DEFAULT COLOR
```

Comment: I will check it today evning and I will tell you that is it correct. Thanks for help

Comment: I had some problems with getApplication() method, because my OnClickListener are not in the activity, but I passed context to my class and now it works fine. Thank you for your help!